# Django filter icontains returns no results when string contains whitespace - mysql.connector.django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a search autocomplete box that returns courses when users enter a query string. This is working fine on my development server, but when deployed to live it only returns results when the user enters a single word and not multiple words separated by spaces. This is an issue as the course titles can contain spaces.

For reasons beyond my control, I am having to use `mysql.connector.django` as the database backend. I have limited access to the configuration of the database.

This is the code that works in development but not in live when querying the same database:

```
courses = (Course.objects.filter(module__open=True, module__term__academic_year__live=True)
           .filter(title__icontains=query)
           .distinct()
           .order_by('category__title', 'title'))
```

These are the database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',

        ...

        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_pure': True
        }
    }
}
```

`use_pure` is set due to [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92001).

I am aware that MySQL queries do not factor in case by default, but I would have thought that using `icontains` would still return results.

Comment: Are you sure that is the `icontains` that's causing your queryset to be None and not the other filters? I'm asking because you do have other filters. Maybe try to remove those and see what you get.

Comment: @HigorRossato I've just simplified the code to `courses = Course.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)` and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: What's inside your "query"? Also, is the DB records locally the same as in production?

Comment: `query` is a simple text string passed to the view. For example, "French" or "French stage 1". I am querying the same database and everything is identical. All the view is really doing is returning the `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` string is passed as a URL parameter, and I found that when it contained a space, the view was trying to process the space as `%20` instead, so obviously no results were returned.

I unquoted the query as follows:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

...

query = unquote(query)
```

I am assuming this is an intricacy of the server. I've never had to do this with my other apps deployed elsewhere. If anyone can confirm however I would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

- Change your Table collations to  `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;`
- Change your Database collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci`;

Now django would handle the rest. It helps to support unicode character and filter starts working using `icontains` filter.

**Note :** try in development server before updating in production directly.